# Why are “binary files” not in raw binary?

Tags: c, binary, executable, machine-code

I have a C program saved in an executable (.exe- I have heard this also referred to as a “binary” file).
When I open that in a text editor, it is not in binary, but in some other wacky assembly of characters. Why is this? what stage of execution does the file actually display? Why does this intermediary text exist between the C code and actual raw binary?

Comment: The executable file contains opcodes, when you view them in a text editor, the editor reads it byte wise any they may not turn out as legible characters.

Comment: Standard ascii character are represented by binary number. Each character, 'a', 'b' have a code. If you open a 'raw binary' file in a text editor it shows the characters corresponding at each binary code. CPU instructions also are each assiciated to a corresponding binary code. When the file is copied in memory the processor executes the instruction for each binary code.

Comment: You can interpret the term "binary" in multiple ways. It does not mean just one thing, and this can be confusing. Sometimes, you should interpret "binary" as "non-text". Sometimes "binary" means something expressed in 1 and 0. When on a Linux system, "binary" sometimes means "executable file or library". Sorry, our language is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "wacky assembly of characters" that you see **is** binary.  Generally speaking, a binary file is any file that is not plain text but instead contains data meant for a program to read instead of a person.

The .exe file you have contains the machine code required to run the program, along with some data describing the layout of the file.

What you see when you open the .exe in a text editor is the editor trying to make sense of what it's reading.  Some of the bytes in the file might be ASCII codes for readable characters, so you'll see those characters in that case.  For  bytes whose ASCII code is not a printable character, the editor attempts to display in some way that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`.exe` is a file extension that stands for **executable**.  An executable file is not source code, it is a file that has been compiled to be ran directly by an operating system.  Those random characters that you see are because the file consists of a series of bytes that are not designed to be viewed as text.

> A binary file is a computer file that is not a text file. The term
>   "binary file" is often used as a term meaning "non-text file". Many
>   binary file formats contain parts that can be interpreted as text; for
>   example, some computer document files containing formatted text, such
>   as older Microsoft Word document files, contain the text of the
>   document but also contain formatting information in binary form.

---

These files are not meant to be read or viewed on text editor like **notepad**. Most text editing programs do not parse binary encoding formats, and are expected to parse ASCII character code formatting.

You need an **disassembler**, a hexadecimal viewer or a specific tool such as readpe to read the content exe files. They But code obfuscation may hinder disassembly. Code might be delibrately obfuscated to make it harder to retrieve the source code.